# double insertion into sql db by asp coding

Tags: asp.net, sql-server-2005

this code works fine but its inserts the same data twice in sql db on just one button click . if i made some mistake plz let me know ..

```
Protected Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim cmd As New SqlCommand
        Dim str As String

        str = "insert into cmember(name,period,design,duty,quali,cont)values ('" & TextBox1.Text & "', '" & TextBox2.Text & "','" & TextBox3.Text & "','" & TextBox4.Text & "', '" & TextBox5.Text & "','" & TextBox6.Text & "')"

        If con.State = ConnectionState.Closed Then
            con.Open()

        End If

        Try
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
            cmd.Connection = con
            cmd.CommandText = str


        Catch ex As Exception

            MsgBox(e.ToString)
        End Try

        If cmd.ExecuteNonQuery Then

            Label1.Text = "entry saved"


            con.Close()
        Else
            Label1.Text = "entry not saved"
        End If
    End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

I can't see the valid reason why it inserts twice a same record in current code snippet. May be a button is hit twice or you are refreshing a web page.

Off-the topic : Do not use hard coded SQL statement. Use parameterized query. (Read about [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection))

```
str = "insert into cmember (name,period,design,duty,quali,cont) values 
                   (@name,@period,@design,@duty,@quali,@cont)"
```

Answer (score 0):

This might seem silly, but you're not double clicking the button, are you ?
Also, never use a Msgbox call in ASP - the messagebox will appear on the server, not on the browser, and it will block the thread until clicked. You're much better to create an ASP Label control and assign the text to that.
Also, the bit enclosed in a Try block is just settings and will never throw an error - the try block should be around the commands where you open the connection, and where you execute the query.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is not appearing to insert this data in twice.

The best way to find out what exactly is happening is to run a trace through SQL Server Profiler.  To do this you need to ensure you have `ALTER TRACE` permissions on the instance.